# Parse text in TextArea and display images based on the path

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am having a HTML5 webpage.
In which I am having a `TextArea` with some raw data.
say something like this.

```
Image1:
C:\Images\image1.jpg
Image2:
C:\Images\image2.jpg
Image3:
C:\Images\image3.jpg
```

I need to parse that textarea and show images in the path below the textarea.
I need to pass that path to the `img src="path"` tag and i should display the images based on the paths in textarea.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Add JavaScript tag to your question if you wish to have a JS solution as pure HTML wont do it

Comment: Are the images going to be on the client's computer, or available somewhere on the internet?

Comment: @GarethCornish: From the client computer.!!

Comment: You'll have to use input elements to get the user to select files and then use the File API to get the image data and use that to create a new Image element. I'm guessing there's no way to get the file path from the image supplied.

Comment: @Sam: No am not supplying images. The text Area would have path of the images residing in local machine. I should extract the path, and display images below the text area.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you can't access Images (or any files) from a clients machine (except in some very specific cases) via JavaScript. EDIT - Unless the image src is the image location, I understand, I see what you mean now and it should work

Comment: I created a jsfiddle to do this (http://jsfiddle.net/jt5yg/6/). The script to extract the filenames was not too difficult, but the browser refuses to show the images. Security restrictions prevent access to the local file system.

Comment: @GarethCornish: It worked fine.Post this as an Answer. Thanx.!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jt5yg/6) to do this. The HTML and Javascript were fairly simple:

```
<textarea id="rawdata" rows="10" style="width: 100%" onchange="processimages();">
</textarea>
<div id="images"></div>
```

and

```
var allfiles = /[a-z]\:\\[\w\\_-]+?\.jpg/gi;
function processimages(){
    var textarea = document.getElementById('rawdata');
    var imagecontainer = document.getElementById('images');
    var file;
    imagecontainer.innerHTML = '';
    while(file = allfiles.exec(textarea.value)){
        imagecontainer.innerHTML += '<img src="file:///'+file+'" />';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I ran the script, the image tags were added, but the browser refused to display them. Security restrictions prevent the browser from accessing the local file system without explicit user action.

This makes sense, of course. If we could do this, hackers could access the contents of hidden system files on your PC the same way.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery it can be like this:

```
var sText = jQuery('textarea_selector').text(),
    aStrings = sText.split('\n');

for(i = aStrings.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    if( aStrings[i].indexOf('\\') != -1 ) {
        jQuery('body').append('<img src="'+aStrings[i]+'">');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var srcs = $('textarea').val().replace(/\\/g, "||");
srcs = srcs.split(/Image\d:/).map(function(el) {
   return el.replace("||", "\\");
});

srcs[0] // C:\Images\image1.jpg
```

You can now iterate over the array and apply src to each Img.